# Open Google Contacts email links in Outlook and not gmail

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, contacts, address

I use Google Contacts as my main address book as it auto syncs with my Android phone.
On my PC, I use MS Outlook (the desktop app) for emails. I tend to have Google Contacts open in a tab in Chrome.

If I click a contact's email address in Google Contacts, it always brings up a gmail email compose window and not the Outlook one.

My mailto: handler is already set to Outlook.

I Inspected the email address element in Chrome and it's not a regular mailto: link.
It's some code that looks like this:

```
<div role="button" class="W7Nbnf" tabindex="0" jsaction="click:h5M12e;clickmod:h5M12e; pointerdown:FEiYhc; pointerup:mF5Elf; pointerenter:EX0mI; pointerleave:vpvbp; pointercancel:xyn4sd; contextmenu:xexox; focus:h06R8; blur:zjh6rb; mlnRJb:fLiPzd;" aria-label="Email: removedforprivacy@somedomain.com" jslog="24336; track:click,impression" jscontroller="LxQ0Q" aria-describedby="ttid-c242">removedforprivacy@somedomain.com</div>
```

I'm no coder, but I'm guessing it's calling some JavaScript function in response to the click?

So, the question is, is there a way to override this behaviour or am I stuck with how Google built it?

As an aside, does `track:click,impression` mean Google is tracking each click?

Comment: Yes, it's javscript and you can't change what it does from the OS.

Comment: This is not feasible.